# Winform, custom title bar with Image and text but no control buttons?

Tags: c#, winforms

In winform application, how do i add image and title text in 'Title bar' and remove all control buttions (min, max & close).  I could able to show image and title text but could not remove all buttons including 'Close' button.  Is ther any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the ControlBox property of the form to False, then u can easily remove all buttons(min, max, Close buttons), and even you can set Title and Image to it, where as using FormBorderStyle it will completely remove title bar ,which will not help your problem.

So i suggest you to set
`ControlBox=false` of the form

Answer (score 0):

Setting the FormBorderStyle to None in FormDesigner may help.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately to do that you need to call Windows API function using PInvoke.

```
  // Changes an attribute of the specified window.          
  [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = false)]
  public static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);
  // Retrieves information about the specified window.        
  [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = false)]
  public static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);
  public const int GWL_STYLE = (-16);
  public const int WS_SYSMENU = 0x00080000;
  public const int WS_MAXIMIZEBOX = 0x00010000;


  public static void SetDialogStyle(Form window)
    {
        // We disable the control box functionality for the window
        // i.e. remove the minimize, maximize and close button as 
        // well as the system menu.

        int style = GetWindowLong(window.Handle, GWL_STYLE);
        style &= ~(WS_SYSMENU | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX);
        SetWindowLong(window.Handle, GWL_STYLE, style);
    }
```

you can call this function in OnLoad event passing **this** as the function's argument.

Comment: where do i call this menthod in from1.cs?

Comment: WindowInteropHelper ?? could not found?

Comment: but this code removes the Header Icon also, but icon should be shown....!! How to do this?

Comment: Dhana you need to play with windows styles http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632600(v=vs.85).aspx adding ot removing them in Style variable