# How to remove the close button, but not its icon?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a windows application develop using C# .net 4.0 version.

I need to remove close button from one of my popup windows. I can do it by setting Control Box property as false. But in that case it will remove my icon as well. Else I can disable the close button. But is there any way to remove close button only (leaving the icon in place)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable Close Button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457307/disable-close-button)

Comment: and this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074385/winform-custom-title-bar-with-image-and-text-but-no-control-buttons

Comment: Actually I needs to remove Close button and not remove the Icon. I have gone through the above link. But I could not find that. Please help

Comment: Do you mean the close button graphic or the form icon graphic?

Comment: i need to remove close button graphic only. Icon graphic shoud need to have. thank you.

Answer (score 5):

This is a bit of a cleaner solution :-)

[Original post](http://sameeramrutia.wordpress.com/2008/09/16/hide-close-button-x-of-win-forms-in-cnet/)

[winuser.h](ftp://ftp.acer-euro.com/gpl/AS9100/GPL_AS9100/MPlayer-0.90/loader/wine/winuser.h)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private const int CS_NOCLOSE = 0x200;
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams mdiCp = base.CreateParams;
            mdiCp.ClassStyle = mdiCp.ClassStyle | CS_NOCLOSE;

            return mdiCp;
        }
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

}
```

According to constants in the winuser.h there are no flags to get rid of the closed button completely.  (Unless you want to find a way to draw over the top of the button by copying a section to the left of it - yuk.)

Comment: Still im unable to find the answer that i wanted.

Comment: Go the other way then.  Set the controlbox to false hiding both icon and buttons then redraw the icon using win32 and intcept message pump.

Answer (score 4):

This code will disable your close button but will show the icon.

In your form class:

Import:

```
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

In the main class:

```
    const int MF_BYPOSITION = 0x400;

    [DllImport("User32")]
    private static extern int RemoveMenu(IntPtr hMenu, int nPosition, int wFlags);

    [DllImport("User32")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetSystemMenu(IntPtr hWnd, bool bRevert);

    [DllImport("User32")]
    private static extern int GetMenuItemCount(IntPtr hWnd);
```

Event:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IntPtr hMenu = GetSystemMenu(this.Handle, false);
        int menuItemCount = GetMenuItemCount(hMenu);
        RemoveMenu(hMenu, menuItemCount - 1, MF_BYPOSITION);
    }
```

Comment: Your code is working fine. But i need to remove the close button. Not disable. Thank you.

Comment: This is ridiculous. Did you unaccept my code and gave me a -15. Thankyou very much for that. You don't expect people to create your program. I gave you this code to put you in some direction.

Comment: Here's a +10 back, because I don't care if the button's still visible, but I do need to conditionally disable it, which your code makes easy.